# Stored procedure produces a different result set on each execution given the same inputs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure to return a paginated set of results based on a bunch of optional search criteria. The procedure uses a temp table so that the total count and page count can be returned separately from the search results. Here's what it looks like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Location_SearchAll]
    @LocationName varchar(100) = null,
    @LocationId varchar(10) = null,
    @Address varchar(40) = null,
    @City varchar(35) = null,
    @StateProvince varchar(2) = null,
    @PostalCode varchar(9) = null,
    @CountryCode varchar(2) = null,
    @PhoneNumber varchar(20) = null,
    @ServiceLevel varchar(35) = null,
    @Page int = 1,
    @ItemsPerPage int = 100
AS
    select * into #temp from Locations l
        where (l.LocationName like '%' + @LocationName + '%' or @LocationName is null)
            and (l.LocationId like '%' + @LocationId + '%' or @LocationId is null)
            and (l.AddressLine1 like '%' + @Address + '%' or @Address is null)
            and (l.City like '%' + @City + '%' or @City is null)
            and (l.StateProvince like '%' + @StateProvince + '%' or @StateProvince is null)
            and (l.PostalCode like '%' + @PostalCode + '%' or @PostalCode is null)
            and (l.CountryCode like '%' + @CountryCode + '%' or @CountryCode is null)
            and (l.Phone like '%' + @PhoneNumber + '%' or @PhoneNumber is null)
            and (l.ServiceLevel like '%' + @ServiceLevel + '%' or @ServiceLevel is null);
    select count(*) as TotalCount, count(*) / @ItemsPerPage + 1 as TotalPages from #temp;
    select * from #temp
        order by Id
        offset (@Page) * @ItemsPerPage - @ItemsPerPage rows
        fetch next @ItemsPerPage rows only;
    drop table #temp;
RETURN 0
GO
```

I'm noticing that, on occasion, this procedure will return a different number of results each time despite having the exact same search criteria defined. Specifically, the count of results will steadily increase with each subsequent execution until the count finally hits the actual number of records that should be returned based on the search criteria. It's as if the results are being returned by the select statements before the temp table is fully populated.

Some points of note:

- This anomaly is reflected in both select statements - the total counts and the results returned.
- I've attempted to replace the temp table with a table variable, but it has the same problem.

I'm guessing this is some dumb thing I'm doing with respect to my usage of temp tables, but I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere explaining what that might be. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Data in a table can change, my guess is that it is. We can't run your code, and we don't have an [mre] here.

Comment: Tip - you'd be better off storing just the keys and joining back to the base table to return the data; Use `@@rowcount` instead of counting; and consider a better *kitchen sink* approach overall, Google that term.

Comment: @Stu - Duly noted. Clearly I need to rethink my approach here. Thanks very much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

@Larnu was right. It was my own dumb, dumb fault. I didn't so much as consider the possibility that the underlying data was changing because this is a local DB and no one else is touching it, and then I remembered I had a recurring ETL scheduled that was refreshing the table every few minutes. That's why my result set was changing.

If I could delete this question and conceal my embarrassment, I would, but in lieu of that I'll just thank @Stu for a concise schooling on stored procedure improvements and hope that my derp moment prevents someone else from making the same mistake.